# Cannot close xe:dialog on XPages with client side validation

Tags: validation, dojo, dialog, xpages

I have an xe:dialog which includes Dojo Form controls to input several values and create a new document when saved.  All values are required and I an using a combination of xe:djValidationTextBox, xe:djTimeTextBox, xe:djComboBox and others to input the values and perform the client-side validation.

Here is an example of one of the input controls:

```
                    <xe:djValidationTextBox
                        id="djValidationTextBox2" value="#{document3.ChemTo}"
                        required="true" invalidMessage="Must enter the To change number"
                        promptMessage="Enter the To change number">
                        <xe:this.converter>
                            <xp:convertNumber type="number"></xp:convertNumber>
                        </xe:this.converter>
                    </xe:djValidationTextBox>
```

The save button works great to create the new document after all validation passes.

```
<xp:button value="Save" id="button7">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete">
                    <xp:this.action>
                        <xp:actionGroup>
                            <xp:saveDocument var="document3">
                            </xp:saveDocument>
                            <xp:executeScript>
                                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var c =  `enter code here`getComponent("dialog1");
 c.hide("panelChemLog");}]]></xp:this.script>
                            </xp:executeScript>
                        </xp:actionGroup>
                    </xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
```

The problem is with the Cancel button.  I still get the client-side validation messages for all required Dojo input controls without a value when I click the Cancel button.  I can successfully cancel the dialog by clicking the big "X" in the top right corner of the dialog, but can't close with the server-side or client-side code for the two cancel buttons below.

```
   <xp:button value="Cancel CS" id="cancelButton">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete">
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog("#{id:dialog1 }" );]]>
          </xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

            <xp:button value="Cancel SS" id="cancel2Button">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var c =       
                                                   getComponent("dialog1");
                                  c.hide();}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
```

How do I code a button to close a dialog and by-pass the client side validation ?

Comment: My advice: make a custom code for close button, that sets specific flag (hidden edit, JS variable) used in CS validator to skip validation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second button (server side), you can disable validation by `immediate="true"` attribute.

```
<xp:button
    value="Cancel SS"
    id="cancel2Button">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete" immediate="true">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
  var c = getComponent("dialog1");
  c.hide();}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

For client-side, it's interesting. If you hide the dialog by dojo-way, it closes normally. I think it's because of the `XSP.closeDialog()` method. This function uses `setTimeout()` for partial-refresh related issues and dojo component cancels the submissions at that time.

So, just use `dijit.byId("#{id:dialog1}").hide();` instead of XSP function on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks Serder, that did it ... and so obvious too.

Comment: It has been a partial solution though. I have looked at it in detail but couldn't find an easy way to disable dojo validation at the client side. I'll update if I can find it. :)

Comment: There it is. I have updated the answer for the client-side one :)

Answer (score 1):

Close the dialog AFTER the onClick events refreshes are done.
Put the XSP.closeDialog("#{id:idName}")   in the onComplete event of the EventHandler

<strike><xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var c = getComponent("dialog1");c.hide();}]]></xp:this.action></strike>

```
<xp:button value="Cancel SS" id="cancel2Button">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                     refreshMode="complete" immediate="true">
        <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog("#{id:"dialog1"}")]]></xp:this.onComplete>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```